# How do you publish files back to VSTS Release Management as part of a release?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to upload log files created by a 3rd party exe during a deployment and including it in the results of my deployment, on a separate tab if possible.

I tried using the publish artifact build tasks but that only works for build not release.

I tried logging tasks but `##vso[build.uploadlog]<local file path>` seems to be for builds as well since it complains about finding a container for the build.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Release management does not have a container for build artifacts, that's why you see this error message.

You can try with following task:

```
Write-host "##vso[task.uploadfile]<filename>"
```

> View and download attachments associated with releases
>
> Would you like to upload additional logs or diagnostics or images when
>   running tasks in a release? This feature enables users to upload
>   additional files during deployments. To upload a new file, use the
>   following agent command in your script:
>
> Write-host "##vso[task.uploadfile]"
>
> The file is then available as part of the release logs. When you
>   download all the logs associated with the release, you will be able to
>   retrieve this file as well.

You can also add a powershell script task in your release definition to read the log files and output it to the console. Then you will be see the content of the log files from "Logs" tab powershell script step. And you can also click "Download all logs as zip" to download the logs.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this should be marked the answer. Sure you can upload the logs like this, but you can't download them. "Download all logs as zip" only gives the use the VSTS logs from each step. How can we get the logs which were uploaded?

Comment: Scratch that, you need to refresh the page before the zip contains the uploaded files.

Comment: Do you know if there's a maximum file size that can be uploaded this way? I'm having problems getting this to work. It seems to work fine for a small zip file but a larger one (approx 40MB) doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

I hope to provide more clarity to those looking for an answer. The accepted answer does work.

I had a lot of files (browser screenshots) to add to the release logs. Here's what I did:

If you have lots of files, Archive them into a zip.
[image]

Attach the zip to the log files via powershell.

[image]

Download the logs

[image]

Unzip and enjoy!

[image]

Comment: thanks for detailed. explanation .what have you been achieveing with publish result task?

Answer (score 2):

@DonRolling, thanks for the detailed answer. In my case instead of adding a new task to compress the folder i just included that part in the powershell:

```
Compress-Archive -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestFolder/ScreenShots" -DestinationPath "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestFolder/ScreenShots" -Force

Write-host "##vso[task.uploadfile]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestFolder/ScreenShots.zip"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar problem but I also wanted to use the *Artifacts* in a subsequent agent phase.

Based on the previous answers I created an Extension that offers the possibility to:

- Upload a file or a folder to the *Release Logs*
- Automatically download an *Artifact* from the logs that was previously uploaded

The upload task is making use of the logging command as it was mentioned before. The download task then queries the Azure DevOps REST Api to download all logs collected thus far, tries to find the specified artifact and copies it to a specific place.

If anyone is interested, it can be found on the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.ReleaseArtifacts)