# How can I save testing results in Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, release

During the release pipeline I'm launching Selenium tests. Those tests, in case of fail, make screenshots. I'm looking for a way to upload them so I could look through them and check what went wrong.

I manage to zip them, but unfortunately none of the upload methods are working on release pipeline.

[image: Used tasks]

Is there a way to save/upload files during release pipeline?

Comment: This old trick probably still works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456303/how-do-you-publish-files-back-to-vsts-release-management-as-part-of-a-release

Comment: @JukkaK thanks, that was helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's and old answer I've found useful:

[How do you publish files back to VSTS Release Management as part of a release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456303/how-do-you-publish-files-back-to-vsts-release-management-as-part-of-a-release)

So if you zip the images and upload them like this, the zipfile appears as a part of logfiles.

On a sidenote, I think you can explore these for more options:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md