# Importing external test results into Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, external, azure-pipelines, test-reporting

I am trying to figure out how to import my external test results into Azure DevOps.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) describes how to publish the results within the same pipeline. But that's not going to help me. We do use Azure pipelines to build and deploy our solution, but the testing is run after that (in a deployed environment), so, outside of the pipeline. We can collect the results (in a Azure DevOps suitable format) and would like to feed it back into Azure DevOps release that did the deployment.
All tips are welcome.

Comment: A similar question was posted some time ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874238/how-can-i-save-testing-results-in-azure-devops-release-pipeline/

Comment: However, you'd probably need a suitable way to wait for the tests to be run before finishing the release stage. Can the test run be triggered from release pipeline? If not, valid options would probably be adding some kind of post deployment gate that waits for the test run to be completed. Haven't actually ever used those. Or a separate stage that would trigger when the test run is complete and collect the results.

Comment: Thanx, Jukka.
The testrun takes approx 6 hours and for that reason we have de-coupled it form the pipeline. We do not want to wait, but still being able to feed the results back into Azure DevOps.
The "post deployment gate" you are mentioning, is there documentation onit, or is it just a concept you thought of?

Comment: Concepts from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops and more specifically here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops . 

Building, say, an API just for polling for test results sounds a bit far fetched to me, so how about adding a stage after the deployment stage with a pre-approval gate with 6 hour delay before evaluation? Or a scedhuled trigger if applicable?

Comment: Thanx! A lot to read and learn. ;-)

BTW: this 6 hours delay does that not block my agent for any other pipeline?

Comment: Release waiting for approval should not consume an agent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops

Comment: Jukka, for a full understanding: so each stage can been seen as a separate process/release?

Comment: From the point of consuming agents, yes; you can have loads of releases waiting for approvals and agents running active releases.

Now, what I don't know and why we're still discussing in comments is this; you have finished all stages of your release, would you be able to upload test results in the way references in the first comment. I've usually had longer test runs as separate releases that are scedhuled to run during the night, so that avoids the issue of reserving an agent for several hours.

Comment: Hi Jukka, thanx for bearing with me. That we are still discussing this is because of me not being sure that we would not "block my agent for any other pipeline". With your last answer that's addressed. Then getting to "would you be able to upload test results in the way references in the first comment" makes sense now. Whether I will be able all now depends on trying your suggestions and see if I can get it working. I surely have enough input for.

Comment: No problem. If you get it to work, do post an answer here detailing what you did.

Comment: Hi @ Luc van Vugt Did you work it out by Jukkak's suggestion. Any updates?

Comment: Hey Levi, no not yet, moet things to do. This will take a while before I get all details understood and implemented.
I will post my findings once I do get it working.