# How to add HTML reports present in agent filesystem as an attachment to release pipeline logs in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-pipelines

A scan task of release pipeline in Azure DevOps generates the report and saves it to the local file system of agent. Is there any approach using which we can obtain the result report from the agent machine and access it directly from log attachments?

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Hi, posted answer is helpful to add the file as attachment, but as mentioned in the answer itself, it is not available for download. I have used 'Send Email' task to fetch the file and send it as an attachment. But for this, we have to setup an SMTP server. Hope this helps. I have added my solution as an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, artifacts are not supported in a release pipeline as of now.

As per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58909984) regarding publishing/downloading artifacts in release pipelines, this feature has been proposed on the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-publish-artifact-from-release-pipeline/823829).

For a workaround, if you wish, you can try [third-party extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.ReleaseArtifacts) from the marketplace.

---

You can use [AddAttachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#addattachment-attach-a-file-to-the-build) task command.

**Usage**

Upload and attach attachment to current timeline record. These files are not available for download with logs. These can only be referred to by extensions using the type or name values.

**Properties**

type = attachment type (Required)
name = attachment name (Required)

**Example**

```
##vso[task.addattachment type=myattachmenttype;name=myattachmentname;]c:\myattachment.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, artifacts are not supported in a release pipeline as of now. Few options that will come handy are:

- Copy or publish the reports to blob storage services from a cloud provider.
- Use 'Send Email' task to send the report as an attachment. To use this, an SMTP server has to be setup. Please find below URL for details:
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask